# What teams play in the Quidditch World Cup?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

Given that Quidditch has a World Cup, what teams are involved? Mainly asking as Scotland hasn't been in a World Cup since the late 90s and wondering if we are as bad at Quidditch as football (hoping with JKs heritage she might have snuck Scotland in?).

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quidditch_World_Cup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Any country can enter a team into the Quidditch World Cup.

Though the countries involved in the Quidditch World Cup varies, any country can enter a team as long as they do so within the required timeframe before the next Cup is held.

> The number of countries that enter a Quidditch team for each World Cup fluctuates from tournament to tournament. Where the wizarding population of a country is small it can be difficult to raise a team of the required standard, but other factors such as international conflict or disaster may affect the entry numbers. However, any country may enter a team within the twelve months following the last final. 
> <sub><sup>*[- History of the Quidditch World Cup (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/history-of-the-quidditch-world-cup)*</sup></sub>

The teams that enter then have to play against each other, and the top sixteen are the ones who’ll actually be able to compete in the Quidditch World Cup itself.

> Teams are then divided into sixteen groups within which every team plays all the others over a two-year period until sixteen winning teams remain. 
> <sub><sup>*[- History of the Quidditch World Cup (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/history-of-the-quidditch-world-cup)*</sup></sub>

Scotland does have its own team and has competed in the Quidditch World Cup before.

> Canada 270 – Scotland 240
>
> A bitter disappointment for Scotland, whose Seeker Hector Lamont missed catching the Snitch by millimetres. In a post-match interview, Hector famously lambasted his father (‘Stubby’ Lamont) for not giving him longer fingers. 
> <sub><sup>*[- History of the Quidditch World Cup (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/history-of-the-quidditch-world-cup)*</sup></sub>

Though they didn’t win the Cup, Scotland made it into at least one final.